# How to return JSON result from java soap web service

Tags: java, json, web-services, soap, gson

Ok guys i have come up with my test code as you suggested to do so. I searched the internet and i get `Gson` that makes the task easy. i tested it by printing the results to the console like this and it returns the expected `json` result

```
public String printJson()
{
    ProductBLL productBLL = new ProductBLL();
    List<String> catList = productBLL.getProductCatagories();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonCatList = gson.toJson(testList);
    System.out.println("Category List: " + jsonCatList);

}
```

**Output**
`Category List: ["Book","Music","Movies"]`

but when i try it in my java soap web service its not working that means the web service is still returning xml.

this is the web service method using `Gson`

```
@WebMethod
public String getCategories()
{
    List<String> catList = ppBll.getProductCatagories();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonCatagoryList = gson.toJson(catList);

    return jsonCatagoryList ;
}
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<S:Body>
    <ns2:getCategoriesResponse xmlns:ns2="http://aman.org/">
        <return>Book</return>
        <return>Music</return>
        <return>Movies</return>
    </ns2:getCategoriesResponse>
</S:Body>
```

but i need it to return `json`. Where should it be modified to make it work in the web service?

Comment: Yes there is a way, why don't you try it yourself? Stackoverflow is not a free c# to java converter. Please do some research yourself, try to write some code yourself and if you have any problems you can come back and ask a specific question about a specific piece of code

Comment: @Lino I have made some research as you said but I didn't find what I am seeing for that is why I came here. I have even seen similar questions but they didn't help me as a begginer...

Comment: This is not a question. This is a "do it for me" post...

Comment: I don't understand why you are downvoted, but where is XML from? I mean, getCategories will return list of string, not XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOAP web service will always return XML, may be you can create another REST web service which will internally call the SOAP WS and produce a JSON. with your REST you can easily do it.

so 
Step 1:

create a REST WS which produces JSON

Step 2:

Call SOAP WS from This REST WS and transform the output to the format you want.

Comment: sorry i for being so late to ask this...can you point me some resources i can use refer

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/   -- this for creating rest API , good to use spring      2. for SOAP client which would call from inside the rest API : https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/       ... Not sure if you are still looking for it but might help someone else